# Constructing file path within Python for Feature Class within Feature Dataset?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, feature-dataset

Based on my understanding of the ArcGIS path structure, a feature class inside a feature dataset inside a geodatabase can be accessed by the following:

```
C:\Menu\Lunch.gdb\Sandwich\Cheese
```

Where Sandwich is the feature dataset and Cheese is the feature class.

In a python script, I want to construct this full path, so that I can check it using `arcpy.Exists(x)`. I have the following variables (pseudocode):

```
WSpace = C:\Menu\Lunch.gdb\
FDSName = Sandwich
FCName = Cheese
```

Concatenating `WSpace` and `FDSName` gives the correct path to the feature dataset. What I need help with is tacking `FCName` onto the end. I would think the following code would work, but it renders a space instead of the backslash character:

```
fullPath = WSpace + FDSName + r"\" + FCName
```

Instead of `r"\"`, I have also tried `"\\"`, and `"/"`, but they all render a space. This seems like a simple syntax problem.

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading the ["String literals"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) section of the Python language reference topic on lexical analysis (how the Python interpreter parses Python source code).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strings, even when marked as `r"Raw strings"`, cannot end with a slash, it needs to be escaped. Should be:

```
fullPath = WSpace + FDSName + "\\" + FCName
```

Or better yet, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
fullPath = os.path.join(WSpace, FDSName, FCName)
```

Comment: I tried both "\\" and "//": neither worked for me. But I like os.path.join(), that looks promising.

Comment: os.path.join worked perfectly. Thank you for adding that tool to my toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but r"\" and r'\' both gave me error. Following one works for me:

```
workspacePath = r'C:\a.gdb'
datasetName = r'dataset'
featureClassName = r'ofc'
featureClassPath = workspacePath+"\\"+datasetName+"\\"+featureClassName
print featureClassPath
```

output: C:\a.gdb\dataset\ofc

Comment: As Jason mentioned, the reason neither `r"\"` or `r'\'` works is the single \ escapes the trailing quote, resulting in a syntax error: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals