# Debugging AttributeError Invalid destination path from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror

I am struggling with using Python to export an mxd to PDF. The final PDF would have 4 pages, each with the same extent but with a different layer displayed. Below is the code I entered into the ArcMap 10.4 Python console and at the bottom is the runtime error I received. There is a lot happening in the runtime error and I don't know which are the key errors, which makes it hard to Google and fix. I can't tell if there is something wrong with my python installation or if there is something wrong with my code.

Can you help me breakdown what this runtime error means (referencing specific snippets from the error message) and how I resolve it?

```
    >>> import os, arcpy
... 
... #Specify output path and final output PDF
... outPath = r"C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\""
... finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(outPath + "mapbook.pdf")
... 
... #Specify the map document and the data frame
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
... df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
... 
... #Turn on visibility for each theme and export the page
... lyrList = ["5ft Contour Intervals", "Satellite Imagery", "Percent Slope", "Aspect (compass degrees)"]
... for lyrName in lyrList:
...      lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyrName, df)[0]
...      lyr.visible = True
... 
...      #Export each theme to a temporary PDF and append to the final PDF
...      tmpPdf = outPath + lyrName + r"\"temp.pdf"
...      if os.path.exists(tmpPdf):
...           os.remove(tmpPdf)
...      arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tmpPdf)
...      finalPdf.appendPages(tmpPdf)
... 
...      #Turn off layer visibility and clean up for next pass through the loop
...      lyr.visible = False
...      del lyr, tmpPdf
... del mxd, df, finalPdf
... 
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1156, in ExportToPDF
    layout.exportToPDF(*args)
AttributeError: Invalid destination path
>>>
```

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50214/constructing-file-path-within-python-for-feature-class-within-feature-dataset which may answer your question (and be a duplicate).

Comment: Why are there two " marks at the end of your outPath variable?

Comment: Ah so the issue is with how I was writing file paths. Thank you. I will review the other answered question, thank you.

Comment: @Jon, I think my thinking was \"" somehow escaped the forward slash. There was an error on that line, I added quotes and it moved on to the next error so I thought it worked. I think there were sooo many wrong things the python gave up on me.